# Problem with Exclusions in Plot3D

Tags: plotting

I found the problem when I tried to draw the picture :

```
EEE = Root[-747000 + 90 Δβ^2 - 
    1800 Δκ - 
    20 Δβ Δκ - 
    90 Δκ^2 - Δβ \
Δκ^2 + (24500 - Δβ^2 + 
       20 Δκ + Δκ^2) #1 - 
    270 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 1];
 Plot3D[
 Evaluate[Re[EEE]], {Δκ, -10, 
  10}, {Δβ, 10, 18}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
 PlotPoints -> 100, Exclusions -> All]
```

Here is the result:
[image]

It can be seen that there is another unexpected discontinuous region(white line) in the picture. Because there is no such thing when I draw the points of this expression by `ListPoint3D`:

```
Flatten[Table[{Δκ, Δβ, 
    Re[EEE]}, {Δκ, -10, 10, 
    0.1}, {Δβ, 10, 18, 0.1}], 1] // 
 ListPointPlot3D[#, PlotStyle -> {PointSize -> 0.005}] &
```

[image]
So what can I do to get rid of the white line in the picture?
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

- I think MMA is right.

```
Clear[f];
f[Δβ_, Δκ_] := 
  Root[-747000 + 90 Δβ^2 - 
      1800 Δκ - 
      20 Δβ Δκ - 
      90 Δκ^2 - Δβ \
Δκ^2 + (24500 - Δβ^2 + 
         20 Δκ + Δκ^2) #1 - 
      270 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 1] // Re;
```

- We can use `FunctionDiscontinuities` to find the sets of discontinuities, it is not a simple line.

```
eqn = FunctionDiscontinuities[ f[Δβ, Δκ], {Δκ, Δβ}]
ContourPlot[eqn // Evaluate, {Δκ, -10, 10}, {Δβ, 10, 18}]
```

[image]

- We can compare the symbolic case and the numerical case.
- The numerical case can't exclude the discontinous points at all. And since `ListPointPlot3D` only plots points, so it can remove the `singular points` (such points have significant height difference), but it still can't exclude the `removable points` (such points have no significant height difference).

```
Clear["Global`*"];
f[Δβ_, Δκ_] := 
  Root[-747000 + 90 Δβ^2 - 
      1800 Δκ - 
      20 Δβ Δκ - 
      90 Δκ^2 - Δβ \
Δκ^2 + (24500 - Δβ^2 + 
         20 Δκ + Δκ^2) #1 - 
      270 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 1] // Re;
g[Δβ_?NumericQ, Δκ_?
    NumericQ] := 
  Root[-747000 + 90 Δβ^2 - 
      1800 Δκ - 
      20 Δβ Δκ - 
      90 Δκ^2 - Δβ \
Δκ^2 + (24500 - Δβ^2 + 
         20 Δκ + Δκ^2) #1 - 
      270 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 1] // Re;
{Plot3D[f[Δβ, Δκ], {\
Δκ, -10, 10}, {Δβ, 10, 18}, 
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, Exclusions -> All, ViewPoint -> Top], 
 Plot3D[g[Δβ, Δκ], {\
Δκ, -10, 10}, {Δβ, 10, 18}, 
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, Exclusions -> All, ViewPoint -> Top]}
```

[image]